# Does this PLS graph show this data can predict the Y variable?

Tags: cross-validation, scikit-learn, partial-least-squares

This graph shows the mean of R squared values from cross-validation using
a range 2-68 for k-fold parameter. The random state value does
not influence this result. PLS regression was used to predict the
Y values.

The dataframe has 68x701 shape. There is one Y variable and the
remaining are spectral curves.

Can I use this data to predict the Y variable?

[image]

Comment: In your graph the R^2 values are ranging between 0 and -40. I suggest you to Google R^2. Also, K-fold vs R2 plot is very unusual. Lastly, in PLS regression you need to choose number of latent variables. Did you choose them manually or let the software do it?

Comment: @theGD R^2 ca be negative as mentioned in this guide
[Guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html).
The PLS regression works well only when the data is random splited (80-20% and random_state=655) and just with 1 latent variable (R^2 = 0.78). This is not reflected in cross-validation process as we see in the previous graph.  In most published papers always use more than one latent variable or factors. I am not sure if I can use PLS in this case.  I'm using sklearn library and Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I don't have the rep to comment yet, is your question "is the method PLS working well for predicting y?" If so then $R^2$(the one sklearn uses) has an upper bound of 1 and no lower bound, therefor your model can be arbitrarily bad (get more negative and negative, in the $R^2$ metric) and it looks like PLS is pretty bad at predicting $y$ (regression context). I would try to figure out why and maybe use other models.

Usually larger(in the positive direction) $R^2$ values mean the model is performing well. $R^2$ is the explained variance / total variance and is often used as a measure of goodness of it.

Because you have far more variables than samples I would try a regularized approach such as Lasso or elastic net

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet.html#sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet

Comment: Edited title in line with @FakeBrain's suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for response and suggestions. I will try to test other regression methods.

Comment: @farliz, you have far more variables than you do samples, I would try LASSO or elastic net. and if you found this helpful and that it answered the question, could you accept that answer?

Comment: @FakeBrain of course you suggestions are useful to me.